# How to understand this Risk Parity Algorithm?

Tags: optimization, risk-parity

I am trying to understand an optimization algorithm to achieve risk parity in a portfolio. I need some help figuring out the notation in the following formula:

[image: Formula, algorithm]

I found this on [THIS](http://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=817078078116004004101107074094088068001008007085063041068117119105027024066001121072026035111101049057019019014024101114003124012022021021058020088096015107092093081008021009007002119111003088106093106116098085001004096085092064110097067102020118102&EXT=pdf) paper.

I understand the following, if you could help me by pointing any mistake, would be great!

I understand that this algorithm is suppossed to iterate the allocation for each asset at a time.

- $x^*_i$ : The iteration n+1 of asset i.
- $σ_i$ : The standard deviation of Asset i
- $x_j$ : allocation for each asset j
- $\sigma_j$ : The standard deviation of asset j
- $\rho_{i,j}$ : This is my biggest question. WHAT is this?
- $b_i$ : The risk budget for the asset, which for risk parity is $\frac{1}{n}$
- $\sigma(x)$ : The standard deviation of the portfolio

What am I missing?

Comment: @AlexC I know the answer is very simple, but please don't answer in comments we will never get these type of questions closed otherwise...

Comment: The link to the paper is broken. I suspect that the capture is from https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05710 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems very simple. The $\rho_{ij}$ are the correlations between asset i and asset j, in other words these are the elements of the correlation matrix. This notation is very standard in portfolio optimization problems. The number of securities n, the n-by-n correlation matrix R and the n vector of $\sigma_j$'s are the main inputs of a risk parity problem.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I was able to solve it after all!