# How to understand this convex optimization method to find risk budget portfolio

Tags: optimization, risk-parity

Both [the short course material coded by the CVXPY developers](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvx_short_course/blob/master/exercises/13.20.ipynb) and [an answer on Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/46813/62548) suggest that given a desired risk budget $b$, we can find the full-investment portfolio with weights $w$ that has the risk budget (as defined in those materials) equal to $b$ by performing the following convex optimization:

$$\begin{align}\text{Minimize}\;&\frac{1}{2}w'\Sigma w - \sum_i b_i\,\text{log}w_i \\
\text{subject to} \;& 1'w=1\end{align}$$

However, having done this myself in Python with CVXPY, I found the resulting risk budgets **were not the same as the desired $b$**.

I then tried to calculate this minimization by hand, and I found that the solution $w$ has

$$(\Sigma w)_i - \frac{b_i}{w_i} = \lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }i$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lagrangian multiplier.

In other words, since we can show that the $i$-th risk budget ${b_w}_i$ by definition is equal to $\frac{w_i(\Sigma w)_i}{w'\Sigma w}$, the solution to that optimization problem has:

$${b_w}_i = \dfrac{b_i+\lambda w_i}{w'\Sigma w} = \dfrac{b_i+\lambda w_i}{1 + \lambda}$$

**and this in general is not equal to $b_i$** (otherwise, $w_i=b_i$). This has been verified by the optimization that I ran in Python.

**But I'm sure this method is not wrong**--there's [an academic paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2297383) written to explain it by Spinu (2013), which is beyond my capabilities. So, I'd really appreciate anyone who can explain this formulation!

### Update:

Here's the Python code that I wrote. It's [an exercise](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvx_short_course/blob/master/exercises/13.20.ipynb) that's part of the CVXPY short course.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp


#input data

Sigma = np.array([[6.1, 2.9, -0.8, 0.1], 
                  [2.9, 4.3, -0.3, 0.9], 
                  [-0.8, -0.3, 1.2, -0.7],
                  [0.1, 0.9, -0.7, 2.3]])
b = np.ones(4)/4  #risk parity


# optimization

w = cp.Variable(4)  #portfolio weight
obj = 0.5 * cp.quad_form(w, Sigma) - cp.sum(cp.multiply(b, cp.log(w)))  #objective
constr = [cp.sum(w) == 1, w >= 0] # constraint
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constr)
prob.solve()


# print the solution weight and solution risk budget

b_w = cp.multiply(w, Sigma @ w) / cp.quad_form(w, Sigma)  #solution risk budget
print("The solution weight is", w.value)
print("The solution risk budget is", b_w.value)
```

And the printed outputs are:

`The solution weight is [0.16073365 0.14918463 0.42056612 0.2695156 ]`

`The solution risk budget is [0.32355772 0.33307394 0.10944985 0.23391849]`

Comment: It would be of great help, if you could post your Python code (or a working example) :-).

Comment: Have you added the non-negativity constraints as well?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I'll try it for more cases. For the specific covariance matrix that I used, it made no big difference, so I assume the optimal solution without this constraint is already non-negative (the code is not at hand at the moment, so I'm not sure if it *really is*.) But even in that case, the solution and the desired risk budget did not agree, so I guess there must be other causes as well. It might've just been a mistake in my code, or in my understanding of it. I'll post a sample code later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem should be solved in two steps: the optimization **without** the condition that the sum equals 1, followed by a normalization step which divides w by sum(w) to produce the desired solution.

Here is the modified code:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp


#input data

Sigma = np.array([[6.1, 2.9, -0.8, 0.1], 
                  [2.9, 4.3, -0.3, 0.9], 
                  [-0.8, -0.3, 1.2, -0.7],
                  [0.1, 0.9, -0.7, 2.3]])
b = np.ones(4)/4  #risk parity


# optimization

w = cp.Variable(4)  #portfolio weight
obj = 0.5 * cp.quad_form(w, Sigma) - cp.sum(cp.multiply(b, cp.log(w)))  
#objective
constr = [w >= 0] # constraint
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constr)
prob.solve()

# normalize

w = w/cp.sum(w)


# print the solution weight and solution risk budget

b_w = cp.multiply(w, Sigma @ w) / cp.quad_form(w, Sigma)  #solution risk budget
print("The solution weight is", w.value)
print("The solution risk budget is", b_w.value)
```

The result

```
The solution weight is [0.13765302 0.11336252 0.4758825  0.27310195]
The solution risk budget is [0.25000012 0.25000013 0.24999967 0.25000007]
```

The marginal values are equal (within numerical error).